# Implementing pagination in async calls

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, pagination

I have an AWS with a large amount of json files. I need to create a function, that will scan every json file for a matching property, and return every match. Further more I need to be able to implement pagination, making it possible to specify an offset and limit that will return a subrange of matches ordered by the s3 key name.

Had the S3 bucket been a sql table and each file a record in the table I would have wrote the following query:

`SELECT * FROM s3 AS file WHERE file.property = <value> ORDER BY file.key LIMIT <offset>,<limit>`

I have created the following utility functions:

- `listKeys()` : returns a promise resolving an array of s3 keys
- `readFile(s3Key)` : returns a promise resolving an object parsed from the json file
- `doMatch(object, value)` : returns a promise resolving true i there is a match, otherwise false

I have created the following code to solve the problem. The problem is that since both `readFile` and `doMatch` works async the matches array will not be ordered but rather random. Due to the amount of files, it is important that I break the iteration as soon as I have the required amount of matches, avoiding reading to many files.

How can I await the promises to resolve in a sequence rather than in parallel?

Thanks :-)

```
function getMatches(value, offset, limit) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        let matches = [];

        listKeys().then((keys) => {
            for (let i = offset; i < keys.length; i++) {
                let key = keys[i];
                readFile(key).then((object) => {
                    doMatch(object, value).then((isMatch) => {
                        if (isMatch) {
                            matches.push(object);
                        }

                        if (matches.length === limit || i === keys.length-1) {
                            resolve(matches);
                        }
                    });
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have those files saved as JSON in S3, you should be able to use [Amazon Athena](https://aws.amazon.com/athena/).

Since you're knowledgeable with SQL, you should be able to construct your own queries.

If will be far easier instead of writing your own query functions.

[Getting Started with Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/getting-started.html)